# oracle: using dbms.random for randomizing characters and numbers

Tags: regex, oracle, replace

I need help on how I can fully randomize the characters and numbers in the address without affecting the spaces. I tried the query below(**PICTURE1**) but it replaces all characters into 1 random character only. Any alternatives or logic to achieve the desired output? thanks

[image]

**RESULT NEEDED SAMPLE ONLY:(***random numbers/letters and same length and spacing position***)**
[image]

Comment: The problem is that the function you used as the replacement argument is evaluated before the regex search is performed, and the result is used as a substitution for *all* matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (depending on your version, this can be simplified to make detecting numeric strings easier/faster):

```
with strings as (
        select 'abc def 123 ktr' colv, 1 id from dual
        union all
        select 'abcdef gh 1trzzz' , 2 id from dual
        )
        select id,
        (select listagg(case when length(regexp_replace(strd,'\d+','0'))=1 then
        rpad(to_char(mod(abs(dbms_random.random()),power(10,length(strd)))),length(strd),'0')
        else dbms_random.string('U',length(trim(strd))) end,' ')
        from (select
        trim(regexp_substr(colv,'(\w*\Z)|(\w* )',1,level)) strd from dual connect by level<=regexp_count(colv,' ')+1)
        ) rand_col
        from strings
/
        ID RAND_COL
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
         1 IYV MFS 609 SRV
         2 GBLPUY LY BHIYNS
```

The idea is to split the strings into words, replace these words with random strings of equal size, and then reconstruct the string.

Comment: i have tried the script, but what i need is the same length and same position of spaces.

Comment: I edited the answer to have the same length

Comment: Already tried using the trim, but what if there are numbers in the address? I also needed to randomize the numbers like the sample picture2.

Comment: I modified my sql to cater for this case.